# Bitcoin script (pay-to-pubkey-hash)

Tags: bitcoind, script

Example for 'pay-to-pubkey-hash' is quoted in Wiki bitcoin script.
I have a doubt that 14 is for bytes to push. But the data to push is 20 bytes.
Please anyone could explain to me?

Script:

76 --> OP_DUP
A9 --> OP_HASH160
14 --> Bytes to push

89 AB CD EF AB BA AB BA AB BA AB BA AB BA AB BA AB BA AB BA --> Data to push

88 --> OP_EQUALVERIFY
AC --> OP_CHECKSIG

Comment: `20` in decimal is equal to `14` in hexadecimal

Answer (score 2):

As [Ugam Kamat](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/90837/ugam-kamat) commented:

> 20 in decimal is equal to 14 in hexadecimal

(Community-Wiki answer to remove Q from unanswered list)